# Inaccurate result from gaussian function

Tags: java, gaussianblur

I have this Gaussian function. which is not producing desired result. for that reason image cannot be blurred properly. In the bellow code I have taken the kernel size(**5**) and sigma value(**1**), which is same as I took in the link below. it would be very helpful if someone could point out the problem.

here is the link of of a website [**Gaussian kernle link**](http://dev.theomader.com/gaussian-kernel-calculator/)

```
public class KernelDemo {

public double[][] Calculate(int lenght, double weight) {
    double[][] Kernel = new double[lenght][lenght];
    double sumTotal = 0;
    int kernelRadius = lenght / 2;
    double distance = 0;

    double calculatedEuler = 1.0 / (2.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(weight, 2));

    for (int filterY = -kernelRadius; filterY <= kernelRadius; filterY++) {
        for (int filterX = -kernelRadius; filterX <= kernelRadius; filterX++) {
            distance = ((filterX * filterX) + (filterY * filterY)) / (2 * (weight * weight));

            Kernel[filterY + kernelRadius][filterX + kernelRadius] = calculatedEuler * Math.exp(-distance);

            sumTotal += Kernel[filterY + kernelRadius][filterX + kernelRadius];
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < lenght; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < lenght; x++) {
            Kernel[y][x] = Kernel[y][x] * (1.0 / sumTotal);
        }
    }
    return Kernel;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    KernelDemo kd = new KernelDemo();
    double terms[][];
    terms = kd.Calculate(5,1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(terms[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions while posting on [so]. Variable names should start with lowercase, method names should start with lowercase.

Comment: thanks. I'll take care of that. please suggest an answer.

Comment: it seems like it is easy to down vote an question very easily!!!

Comment: Why are you allocating 1111 `double[]`s the length of 1111 just to turn around and shove a `double[5][5]` into the same variable?

Comment: that is the size of array. does it matter?

Comment: someone suggested floating point number inaccurate. But i could not find it.

Comment: `double terms[][] = new double[1111][1111];
    terms = kd.Calculate(5,1);`

  `terms` is no longer a `double[1111][1111]` as you are setting it to the return value of `.calculate()` which is a `double[5][5]`

Comment: I just don't understand why you don't just `double[][] terms = kd.calculate(5, 1);`

Comment: yeah, Corrected it. please tell the solution of my problem

Comment: I think you're making this way more complicated than it needs to be, I just looked back at some old code of mine and I was able to do this exact thing in less than 15 lines and that included normalizing the data within the Kernel

Comment: @CraigR8806 could you post the code. how you did?

Comment: @NEKIBURRAHMAN Posted my code.  If it works for you, please upvote and accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to my post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146328/discussion-between-nekibur-rahman-and-craigr8806).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have handled generating a 2d Gaussian distribution kernel.  The `Kernel` class is just a `double[][]` wrapped to enforce certain stipulations (e.g. squared array 5x5 7x7, and also ensures that the length is odd)

```
public static Kernel generateBlurKernel(int length, double std){
    Kernel out = new Kernel(length);

    int center = length/2;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<length;j++){
            int x = Math.abs(j-center);
            int y = Math.abs(i-center);
            out.setValueAt(j, i, ((1d/(2*Math.PI*std*std))*Math.pow(Math.E, -((x*x)+(y*y))/(2*std*std))));
        }
    }
    out.normalize();
    return out;
}
```

In case you want it, here is my `Kernel` class too:

```
public class Kernel {

    private final double[][] matrix;

    public Kernel(int sidelength){
        if((sidelength&1)==0)throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        matrix = new double[sidelength][sidelength];
    }


    public double getValueAt(int x, int y){
        return matrix[x][y];
    }
    public void setValueAt(int x, int y, double value){
        matrix[x][y] = value;
    }
    public double sum(){
        double sum = 0.0d;
        for(double[] da:matrix){
            for(double d:da){
                sum+=d;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public double[][] getFullKernal(){
        return matrix;
    }
    public int getSideLegth(){
        return matrix.length;
    }
    public void normalize(){
        double normalizedConstant = 1d/sum();
        for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<matrix.length;j++){
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j]*normalizedConstant;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not generating the same result as the above website i have mentioned. but it works.

Comment: The difference in results may be attributed to the way that different languages and different implementations of the Java Virtual Machine or even the JDK handle floating point numbers like the `double` @NEKIBURRAHMAN